# Остановка сайдбара над футером

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

При скролле скрипт добавляет сайдбару класс .fixed

```
position: fixed;
```

Есть способы убрать этот класс или добавить другой, чтобы сайдбар не залезал на футер, а замирал до него?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function($) {
    $nav = $('.fixed-div');
    $nav.css('width', $nav.outerWidth());
    $window = $(window);
    $h = $nav.offset().top;
    $window.scroll(function() {
      if ($window.scrollTop() > $h) {
        $nav.addClass('fixed');
      } else {
        $nav.removeClass('fixed');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: [sticky?](https://webref.ru/course/position/sticky)

Comment: @andreymal нет.

Comment: Делал похожее корявым путём, но работает. При скрлолле добавляем класс, далее сравниваем отступ футера от верха страницы примерно там смотрим что когда нужный нам блок будет иметь отступ от верха ~ такой же как у футера убираем фикс класс и добавляем марджин сверху (либо как вариант position absolute + отступ top)

Comment: @DmitriyGorbachew почему нет?

Answer (score 1):

Основная идея - когда нижняя граница header становится меньше 0, устанавливаем  top: 0.
Когда, верхняя граница footer появляется в видимой части экрана - удаляем значение top и выставляем значение bottom равным абсолютному значению разницы высоты экрана и координат верхней границы footer.

```js
var header = document.querySelector('.header');
var sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar');
sidebar.style.top = header.getBoundingClientRect().bottom.toString() + 'px';
var footer = document.querySelector('.footer');

window.addEventListener(
  'scroll',
  scrollHandler,
  false
);

function scrollHandler(e) {
  if ((footer.getBoundingClientRect().top - window.innerHeight) < 0) {
    sidebar.style.top = '';
    sidebar.style.bottom = Math.abs(footer.getBoundingClientRect().top - window.innerHeight).toString() + 'px';
    return;
  }
  if (header.getBoundingClientRect().bottom < 0) {
    sidebar.style.top = 0;
  } else {
    sidebar.style.top = header.getBoundingClientRect().bottom.toString() + 'px';
  }

}
```

```css
:root {
  --hue: 180;
  --saturation: 100%;
  --lightness: 100%
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.main {
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  display: flex;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3rem;
  background-color: hsl( var(--hue), calc(var(--saturation) * 0.5), calc(var(--lightness) * 0.5));
}

.sidebar {
  width: 33%;
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: hsl( calc(var(--hue) * 0.5), calc(var(--saturation) * 0.2), calc(var(--lightness) * 0.2));
  position: fixed;
}

.content {
  width: 66%;
  margin-left: 34%;
  height: 40rem;
  background-color: hsl( calc(var(--hue) * 1.5), calc(var(--saturation) * 0.2), calc(var(--lightness) * 0.2));
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3rem;
  background-color: hsl( var(--hue), calc(var(--saturation) * 0.2), calc(var(--lightness) * 0.2));
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```